# Python: msvcrt.getch() returns wrong string

Tags: python, key, hotkeys, getch

I'd like to receive a keyboard input, but `getch()` doesn't return what I want. It always returns `ÿ` even if I don't press anything. Do you know why? My Script:

```
from msvcrt import getch
while 1:
     print( chr( getch()[0] ) )
```

Comment: I also dont know the specifics but it has something to do with how the microsoft library works. If I wanted to know more I would read its documentation. If you just want the input from the console, use `txt = input("insert txt")`

Comment: I wan't a press on the space key.. And It'd be nice, if it was outside the console. It'll be a game.

Comment: If you are making a game, then you should look into [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about).  It has built-in facilities for handling input while the game is running.

Comment: And the command works in the shell console... AND I DON'T GET WHY!!! xD Sorry for that.